# Calling method in object from object within it

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I have the following problem, and no idea how to solve it. Let's say we have a class `classA`, and in this class is the main method creating an object of the class itself. Now we take another class, `classB`. In the constructor of `classA` we make an object of `classB`. Now in a method of `classB` we want to call a method of `classA`.

Let me provide you with an example.

```
public class classA {
    public classA() {
        //some code
        classB objectB = new classB();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        classA objectA = new classA();
        //more code
    }

    public void methodA() {
        //even more code
    }
}

public class classB {
    public void someListener() {
        //code needed to call methodA of the object objectA
    }
}
```

The question is: what would the code be, where there is now just the comment `//code needed to call methodA of the object objectA`?

The reason I'm in this situation, is that in the code that I'm going to use it for, there are various methods running in `objectB` controlled by loops, but once a certain thing happens a method in what is shown here as `objectA` has to be called. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple ... just pass the reference of class A object to object of class B. Let class B store the reference and call the methods of A whenever necessary.

### New Code (commented)

```
public class classA{
    classA{
        //some code
        classB objectB = new classB(this);  //------------- pass reference here
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        classA objectA = new classA();
        //more code
    }
    public void methodA(){
        //even more code
    }
}

public class classB{
    private classA storedReference = null; //------------- you need a variable of classA to store the reference

    public classB(classA passedObject){   //------------- you need an appropriare constructor
        storedReference = passedObject;   //------------- store the classA object reference
    }

    public void someListener(){
        storedReference.methodA();       //------------- call methods whenever necessary
        //code needed to call methodA of the object objectA
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I didn't know of references and such, but know I can see how this might look like a stupid question :P. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference to ClassA to the constructor in ClassB e.g

```
class ClassB(ClassA ref) {
    ref.someMethod();
}
```

However you need to be careful if you're calling a method on an instance of a class that you're constructing. The class may not have completed its construction and may be be in an incomplete state.

Comment: Yes, there has to be a better strategy for event handling. OP needs to figure this out :) Maybe have static methods to get appropriate data ? :)

Comment: I know it can be done easier when it's an event. I just used eventhandler as an example, because where the method of objectA has to be called is a method as a result of a method called by the eventhandler, but I thought that would be more infomation than useful :P

Comment: @user1816721 I am glad I could help. Just consider what Brian Agnew said. Use it only when you are completely sure that the class is fully constructed :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add constructor to your classB, so that you can pass a classA as reference to it.

So your classB becomes:

```
public class classB {
    classA cA;

    public classB(classA cA) {
        this.cA = cA;
    }

   public void someListener(){
        cA.methodA();
   }
```

}

And your classA constructor :

```
classA{
    //some code
    classB objectB = new classB(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ClassB`, you want to call a method of `ClassA`.  That's not difficult to do, but I believe you have your relationships incorrect.

- **If you're using the current code you have:** You need to pass an instance of `ClassA` to `ClassB`, which can be accomplished using the `this` operator:

  ```
  public classA() {
      //some code
      classB objectB = new classB();
      objectB.someListener(this);
  }
  ```

  In classB:

  ```
  public void someListener(classA theClassA) {
      //code needed to call methodA of the object objectA
      theClassA.methodA();
  }
  ```
- **If you want to reverse the relationships between the two:**  Instead of having an instance of `classB` in `classA` that relies on `classA` to do its work, have `classB` be the dominant object, and have it contain and instance of `classA`.